# Is there anyway to add an uneditable field in magento 2 admin form?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

IS there anyway to add an uneditable field in magento 2 admin form?

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'giftcard_comment',
            'textarea',
            [
                'label' => __('Comment'),
                'title' => __('Comment'),
                'name' => 'giftcard_comment',
                'required' => false,
                'editable' => false
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set true and false by param value using this below way :

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
$fieldset->addField(
    'giftcard_comment',
    'textarea',
    [
        'label' => __('Comment'),
        'title' => __('Comment'),
        'name' => 'giftcard_comment',
        'required' => false,
        'readonly' => $id ? true : false
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `'readonly' => true`  insted of `'editable' => false`

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$fieldset->addField(
            'giftcard_comment',
            'textarea',
            [
                'label' => __('Comment'),
                'title' => __('Comment'),
                'name' => 'giftcard_comment',
                'required' => false,
                'readonly' => $id ? true : false
            ]
        );
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My is issue is that I want the field disabled only on edit form not on create new form. If I make it readonly then it'll get disabled on create form as well!!

Comment: Get params and check with inline if condition. if you get param then it's true otherwise it's false. I have updated my code please review it.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but Rohan Hapani gave the perfect answer first. Therefore I marked it as the correct answer. Much appreciated